# How to delete a Phoenix Session?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm going through the [Phoenix Guide on Sessions](http://www.phoenixframework.org/v0.13.1/docs/sessions). It explains it very well how I can bind data to a session using `put_session` and fetch the value later using `get_session` but it doesn't tell how I can delete a User's session.

From the guide:

```elixir
defmodule HelloPhoenix.PageController do
  use Phoenix.Controller

  def index(conn, _params) do
    conn = put_session(conn, :message, "new stuff we just set in the session")
    message = get_session(conn, :message)

    text conn, message
  end
end
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found it in the [Plug Docs](http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html):

> **[`clear_session(conn)`](http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#clear_session/1)**
>
> Clears the entire session.
>
> This function removes every key from the session, clearing the
>   session.
>
> Note that, even if clear_session/1 is used, the session is still sent
>   to the client. If the session should be effectively dropped,
>   configure_session/2 should be used with the :drop option set to true.

---

You can put something like this in your `SessionsController`:

```elixir
def delete(conn, _) do
  conn
  |> clear_session()
  |> redirect(to: page_path(conn, :index))
end
```

and add a route for this in your `web/router.ex`.

Answer (score 13):

I think what you're looking for is [configure_session](http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#configure_session/2):

```
Plug.Conn.configure_session(conn, drop: true)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure what to go with. `clear_session` or `configure_session`.

Comment: Not sure either, but `conn |> configure_session(:drop)` seems to totally nuke it, so it's a safer bet if you want that

Comment: Just tried this, I get the exception: `(Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Access not implemented for :drop, only the nil atom is supported`

Comment: Hm, I think I misread that - it needs to be a keyword list - updated the answer

Comment: drop session is going to completely nuke it, forcing the browser to remove the cookie. clear_session is just going to clear the data in the session, the cookie continues there.

Comment: how to check whether session is nil/empty or not

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete a particular session you should use:

```
conn |> fetch_session |> delete_session(:session_to_delete)
```

**More informations here:**

https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/blob/master/lib/plug/session.ex#L114:L115

Answer (score 0):

Use only [delete_session/2](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#delete_session/2) to remove the session that you create before, and then redirect to login or something!

Example:

```
# In this example I use a log_out link to delete session when user click in it.
def log_out(conn, _params) do
    conn
    |> delete_session(:session_name)
    |> redirect(to: Routes.auth_path(conn, :login))
end
```

The important thing is return the `conn` modified, removing the key that you put in it.